# Overriding the Request and Testing

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony5

I have an issue with extending the default Request class from Symfony and writing unit tests.

I set a request factory in `index.php` after that set some properties to the custom Request in a RequestListener and it works fine, but when I run a test class, it breaks.

**Here is the index.php:**

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
Request::setFactory(function (array $query = [], array $request = [], array $attributes = [], array $cookies = [], array $files = [], array $server = [], $content = null) {
    return new \App\Extension\HttpFoundationExtension\Request($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
});
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**Here is also the test class:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Api;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;

class AccountTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testGetCollection(): void
    {
        $response = static::createClient()->request("GET", "/accounts");
        self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(201);
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but if I extend the WebTestCase and not the `ApiTestCase class` from the test, the `index.php` is started.



I found the following info in **Symfony docs**, but I don't know how this can help me. :)

> To run your functional tests, the `WebTestCase class` needs to know
> which is the application kernel to bootstrap it. The kernel class is
> usually defined in the `KERNEL_CLASS` environment variable (included
> in the default .env.test file provided by Symfony):
> If your use case is more complex, you can also override the
> `createKernel()` or `getKernelClass()` methods of your functional
> test, which take precedence over the `KERNEL_CLASS` env var.

Here are some useful links I found on this topic:

- Testing and the Kernel: Click [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#your-first-functional-test) to view
- Overriding the Request: Click [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#overriding-the-request) to view

**EDIT**:

Here is my tests/bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';
} elseif (method_exists(Dotenv::class, 'bootEnv')) {
    (new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
}
```

Here is phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bin/.phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="8.5" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>

    <!-- Run `composer require symfony/panther` before enabling this extension -->
    <!--
    <extensions>
        <extension class="Symfony\Component\Panther\ServerExtension" />
    </extensions>
    -->
</phpunit>
```

Here is part of .env.test:

```
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
```

**With this configuration I still have the same issue!**

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of the `KERNEL_CLASS` in your `.env` confiugration?

Comment: I am not sure the test issue is related to your custom request. It seems to be a test-bootstrap issue. Check your `phpunit.xml.dist` and `.env.test` for the `KERNEL_CLASS` and if it matches `App\Kernel` or the name of your custom kernel and if the class is loaded/loadable via the autoloader for tests. You seem to extend the WebTestCase with your `ApiTestCase` what does that class look like?  edit: nevermind, just noticed it's from api-platform

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.env.test` file and search for a `KERNEL_CLASS` declaration. If not present add it (ex: `KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'`).

.env.test:

```
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
```

Then check that the bootstrap test file is loading the .env file using the Dotenv component (and check that the dotenv component is installed). This file is usually located at `tests/bootstrap.php`.

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

require \dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

if (\file_exists(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php')) {
    require \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';
} elseif (\method_exists(Dotenv::class, 'bootEnv')) {
    (new Dotenv())->bootEnv(\dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
}
```

Verify that the `phpunit.xml` (or `phpunit.xml.dist`) is requiring it via the `bootstrap` attribute of the root `phpunit` tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit ... bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
    ...
</phpunit>
```

Your error should be gone now.

I don't think that request override plays a role in your error. Anyway, it is documented in code that setting the request factory is left only for BC. You can just call `createFromGlobals` from *your* extended Request class to have exactly the same result.

Comment: Hi, Thank you the help, but I have all of the code you shared by default.